# <UL> displaying incorrectly - works fine in all browsers except Firefox 2 (screenshots included)

Tags: css, firefox, xhtml, firefox2

OK, here's a screenshot of what it's **SUPPOSED** to look like:

[image: ul displaying correctly]

And here's a screenshot of how it looks in Firefox 2 (on both Mac & PC)...

[image: ul displaying incorrectly]

Every other browser gets it right (even IE6?!).

The source code is an Unordered List using Sprites with :hover effects. Here is some code for you:

The HTML:

```
<div id="votes">
    <ul id="voteOptions">
        <li id="labour"><a href="#">Labour</a></li>
        <li id="conservative"><a href="#">Conservative</a></li>
        <li id="libdem"><a href="#">Liberal Democrat</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#votes {
 width:653px;
 position:relative;
 top:-440px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

ul#voteOptions li a{  
    height: 75px;  
    float: left;  
    text-indent: -9999px;  
    margin-bottom:50px;
}  

ul#voteOptions li#labour a{  
    width: 653px;  
    background: url('votes.png') no-repeat 0px -2px; 
}

ul#voteOptions li#labour a:hover{  
    background: url('votes.png') no-repeat 0px -77px;  
}

ul#voteOptions li#conservative a{  
    width: 653px;  
    background: url('votes.png') no-repeat 0px -152px;  
}
//...
//(etc. etc - code repeats for conservative and libdem, you get the idea).
```

So what am I doing wrong? I've tried lots of stuff but can't seem to get this darn thing to work in FF2.

Jack

Comment: The first screenshot doesn't work.

Comment: This would be easier to sort out with a live link to apply Firebug on. Would that be possible by any chance?

Comment: Direct link to first screenshot: http://i40.tinypic.com/2dqnd7d.png

Comment: @Jack no I mean a live link to the HTML page?

Comment: I'll stick the code into a blank page for you. Give me two minutes and I'll send a link! :)

Comment: This is all too confusing, @Pekka the link was for @SLaks!

Comment: OK @Pekka and others - sample at http://jackwebbheller.com/stackoverflow/

Comment: No worries y'all. Ivo Sabev has solved my problem. Thanks for your offerings of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ul#voteOptions li { clear: both; }` fixing the issue?

Comment: A work of genius good sir! I doubted this would work since I'd tried adding a clear:both directly after each </li> but this worked brilliantly! Thanks!